# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable python raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I wrote a small function in python which should detect circles in the cameraframe of my raspberry pi. But I got this error and don't know why?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 200, in <module>
    rescue()
  File "main.py", line 124, in rescue
    for (x, y, r) in circles:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

this is the function rescue:

```
def rescue():
    cv2. destroyAllWindows()
    global rescue
    rescue = True
    while rescue: 
        # load the image, clone it for output, and then convert it to grayscale
        image = frame.array
        output = image
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # detect circles in the image
        circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.55, 300)

        # ensure at least some circles were found
        if circles is not None:

            # convert the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles to integers
            circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")

        # loop over the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles
        for (x, y, r) in circles:
            cv2.circle(image, (x, y), r, (255, 255, 0), 4)
            cv2.rectangle(image, (x - 5, y - 5), (x + 5, y + 5), (0, 0, 255), -1)

            print(str((x-160)).encode()) #output values 
            
    
        cv2.imshow("output", image)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        rawCapture.truncate(0)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You handled the case `if circles is not None`. What is going to happen `if circles is None` ? (hint: the error you showed us...)

Comment: Seems like your `for` loop should be indented to be inside of the `if circles is not None` check.

Comment: Now it works, it was just an indendent BLock error. As you wrote before I simply had to indent the for loop. Thanks